# Devise rails get error 500 for sign_in page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

i got a problem with my rails project. I have the following error when I want I am in the sign_in page of devise : [Sign up page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ugh6d.jpg)

And I have nothing in my log : [Log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xMxdO.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please share your research oin this topic and detils o your code!

Comment: How much research effort is expected https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users and How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve might be helpful to improve your question.